# Resetting x and y coordinates in r

Tags: r, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am working with Soccer stats and have y and x locations for every event that happens during a game (i.e. pass, shot...). The coordinates are set in the center of the field. I am looking for help on how to reset the coordinates to the bottom left corner of the field. resetting the coordinates will help with the teams switch sides at the half. My end goal is to figure out how many passes were made in the defending teams half, goal box, third, etc...

Any help on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the range of your coordinates (i.e. min & max of x & y)?

Comment: X max=5250 min=-5250 and the Y max=3410 min=-3695

Comment: Add to each `X` `abs(min(X))` and to each `Y` `min(abs(Y))`?